# Close all div click document

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list with link open each sidebar (by data-sidebar name).

```js
const sidebarTrigger = document.querySelectorAll(".js-sidebar-trigger");

// console.log(sidebar);

sidebarTrigger?.forEach(btn => {
  const name = btn.dataset.sidebar;
  const sidebar = document.querySelector(".js-sidebar-" + name);
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    opensidebar(sidebar);
  });
});

function opensidebar(el) {
  el.classList.add("translate-x-0");
  el.classList.remove("translate-x-full");
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function closesidebar(el) {
  el.classList.add("translate-x-full");
  el.classList.remove("translate-x-0");
  document.body.style.overflow = "";
}


document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  sidebarTrigger?.forEach(btn => {
    const name = btn.dataset.sidebar;
    const sidebar = document.querySelector(".js-sidebar");
    const sidebarName = document.querySelector(".js-sidebar-" + name);

    if (!btn.contains(e.target) && !sidebar.classList.contains("translate-x-0")) {
      closesidebar(sidebarName);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.js-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.translate-x-full {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.translate-x-0 {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="js-sidebar-trigger" data-sidebar="one" href="#home">sidebar 1</a>

    <div class="translate-x-full js-sidebar js-sidebar-one">
      1
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="js-sidebar-trigger" data-sidebar="two" href="#home">sidebar 2</a>

    <div class="translate-x-full js-sidebar js-sidebar-two">
      2
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="js-sidebar-trigger" data-sidebar="three" href="#home">sidebar 3</a>

    <div class="translate-x-full js-sidebar js-sidebar-three">
      <a href="#link">3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Question:** How close all sidebar after close out of link (click on document) only javascript?

I've already tried everything, but it doesn't work.
what's my mistake?
There can be links inside sidebars and they should work.

more details more details more details

Comment: There's no need for the optional chaining in `sidebarTrigger?.forEach` `querySelectorAll()` will never return `null/undefined`, it always returns a `NodeList` that you can iterate over. If nothing matches, it returns an empty list, not `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the condition  `&& !sidebar.classList.contains("translate-x-0")`. The class is added when the sidebar is opened, so this condition will not be true for a sidebar that needs to be closed.

```js
const sidebarTrigger = document.querySelectorAll(".js-sidebar-trigger");

// console.log(sidebar);

sidebarTrigger?.forEach(btn => {
  const name = btn.dataset.sidebar;
  const sidebar = document.querySelector(".js-sidebar-" + name);
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    opensidebar(sidebar);
  });
});

function opensidebar(el) {
  el.classList.add("translate-x-0");
  el.classList.remove("translate-x-full");
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

function closesidebar(el) {
  el.classList.add("translate-x-full");
  el.classList.remove("translate-x-0");
  document.body.style.overflow = "";
}


document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  sidebarTrigger?.forEach(btn => {
    const name = btn.dataset.sidebar;
    const sidebar = document.querySelector(".js-sidebar");
    const sidebarName = document.querySelector(".js-sidebar-" + name);

    if (!btn.contains(e.target)) {
      closesidebar(sidebarName);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.js-sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.translate-x-full {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.translate-x-0 {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="js-sidebar-trigger" data-sidebar="one" href="#home">sidebar 1</a>

    <div class="translate-x-full js-sidebar js-sidebar-one">
      1
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="js-sidebar-trigger" data-sidebar="two" href="#home">sidebar 2</a>

    <div class="translate-x-full js-sidebar js-sidebar-two">
      2
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="js-sidebar-trigger" data-sidebar="three" href="#home">sidebar 3</a>

    <div class="translate-x-full js-sidebar js-sidebar-three">
      <a href="#link">3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```